# What does @prim: stands for?

Tags: css, tags, less

I have some .css file with @prim: #colorCode , what does @prim stands for? Since it is used only in one place i cant figure out purpose of @prim. And eclipse is reporting error "Unexpected token".  Any other avariable with @ does not report an error!

```
@prim: #39396A; // <--here is error still existing, 
button {
 color: @prim;
}
```

And there are no error reports on other css variables.

p.s. At the moment that I am writing this I am not aware of *less* I am just using css (or less) from time to time to make some minor changes.

Picture of error to get everything clear Because of some "strange" edits made by some clairvoyant SO  [image]

Comment: You should not modify your question so it contains no error you asked of anymore as this will confuse future readers. (`<<--here is error` comment looks there like "the error is in that line"). If you want it to have correct code place it below the original one (or better write it as an answer. The question should not answer itself).

Comment: This code above contains error, and error is still there!! I have just pointed out where it is. I have accepted that answer because the word in question is not reserved name, and I am assumeing that Eclipse is "doing something wrong" because everything works. So thanks for downwote! But question was What does @prim: stands for? and answer is - FOR NOTHING.

Comment: First of all I did not downvote (never guess who's downvoting to not make others to guess something of you). Secondary with your new edit it becomes much more evident what the error is. It is as simple as: CSS does not have any `@` variables feature, so Eclipse is correct in this case since `@prim: #36296E` is not valid CSS code. Files containing Less code should have `less` extension so either IDE or compiler itself could properly recognize the syntax.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry for guess what did you do and what didnt. Wasnt aware of that my guessing will make other do the same..  My questuon was not clear, so you have assumed ... my bad, whatever. I am done with this one, I have find out that there is less, that it is not css .. I am satisfied. Thanks, bye.

Comment: Well, the important thing to have in mind is that the SO not just for solving your personal problem but also (and more important) for future visitors/readers to find there answers too if those are already there. So while the "is prim reserved name?" - "no" pair is valid thing and made you be happy, neither question nor the accepted answer tell the story of the error (assuming it *is* the error that made you to ask the question, and it has *absolutely totally nothing* with either CSS or Less "reserved" keywords).

Comment: But never mind, just trying to make it clear why I made the rollback initially (because missing `;` or `:` *will* result in the same "Unexpected token" error even if it was Less and not CSS code and that was the main point of my confusion, and your edits just invalidated most of the statements of the answer you accepted yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be Primary Colour. It is just a variable name. In LESS, anything starting with a `@` is a variable. It can also be:

```css
@lol: #39396A;
button {
 color: @lol;
}
```

Moreover it should have a `:` before that! So could be that. Add a `:` like above and the error should go. There is a semi-colon missing too!

To answer your question: `@prim` is **not** a reserved name.

Comment: Parveen thanks, I am not very familiar with css, but I have a lot of variables declared with @someVar, and the only one that report error is this one so I thought it is reserved word or somethig ..

Comment: Please note, that this **is not** CSS, but [Less](http://lesscss.org/). "*Less is a CSS pre-processor, meaning that it extends the CSS language, adding features that allow variables, mixins, functions and many other techniques that allow you to make CSS that is more maintainable, themable and extendable.*"

Comment: `prim` is not a reserved name.

Comment: So basicly my question was is prim reserved name. Thanks!